# Cannot find reference 'DjangoWhiteNoise' in 'django.py' in wsgi.py

Tags: django, heroku, pycharm, wsgi, whitenoise

Im about to deploy my django-app to heroku. I will then use whitenoise to handle the static files. The tutorial im following tells me i have to add this to my wsgi.py file:

[image: wsgi.py file]

So the problem is that pycharm tells me: "Cannot find reference 'DjangoWhiteNoise' in 'django.py'"
However i have installed whitenoise! and it is located in the "External libraries". I even went down into the whitenoise.django file, and there is nothing named DjangoWhiteNoise there...

Thanks in advance. Havent found anythin about this concrete problem anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is for an older, outdated version of WhiteNoise.

There are up-to-date instructions here:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: Okay i see, thanks! After looking at the page you sent it looks like i already have everything i need, so you think i can remove the whitenoise-code from the wsgi-file?

Comment: That's right, yes. There's no need to add anything to `wsgi.py` anymore.